# Traversing a tree that has an arraylist containing an arbitrary number of sub-trees as its children

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

I am doing some exam revision and found this question on a past exam paper:

[image]

[image]

Firstly, would anybody ever implement a tree like this or is it simply a an exam problem?

Secondly, I am really confused about how to go about this. I wanted to use BFS or DFS but they only work for binary trees and I'm not very good with recursion so have struggled there as well.

I have come up with this which works but its really ugly and won't work for a general case, only this particular tree:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getLeafValues() {
    ArrayList<Integer> leafList = new ArrayList<>();
    Tree current = this;
    for (Tree t : current.children) {
        if (t.children.isEmpty()) {
            leafList.add(t.data);
        } else {
            for (Tree t2 : t.children) {
                if (t2.children.isEmpty()) {
                    leafList.add(t2.data);
                } else {
                    for (Tree t3 : t2.children) {
                        if (t3.children.isEmpty()) {
                            leafList.add(t3.data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return leafList;
}
```

Any help on this would be great, as I said before its exam revision, not homework. Thanks

Comment: Consider using recursion for solving this problem.

Comment: `I wanted to use BFS or DFS but they only work for binary trees` no they work for any trees.

Comment: Ah oh ok I was mistaken, thanks @csehydrogen

Comment: _Firstly, would anybody ever implement a tree like this or is it simply a an exam problem?_ Sure, a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is one such example.

Answer (score 1):

Such problems can be solved with recursion:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getLeafValues() {
    ArrayList<Integer> leafList = new ArrayList<>();
    getLeaves (this, leafList);
    return leafList;
}

public void getLeaves (Tree current, List<Integer> leafList)
{
    if (current.children.isEmpty()) {
        leafList.add(current.data);
    } else {
        for (Tree t : current.children) {
            getLeaves (t, leafList);
        }
    }
}
```

The recursion ends when you reach a leaf (i.e. a Tree without children), in which case you add that leaf to the `List`.

If the current node has children, you call the method recursively on all the children, to collect the leaves of their sub-trees.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! It hadn't occurred to me to implement a hepler method.